# Is there somewhere where the Stretch exercises are compiled?

Tags: resources, stretch

The manga *Stretch* is a story about two girls living together who come to love stretching.

Usually the stretches they do are introduced in a small panel with a little bit of demonstration:

[image]

However, there is some story elements in the manga and also the types of stretches are often spread out in different places (example: stretches to do before you go to bed occur interspersed in several chapters)

Is there an existing convenient way of seeing these stretches grouped together rather than having to compile them manually?

I know there are groups that will compile anime cookbooks, so I don't think it's too out-of-the-ordinary that something like this may exist

Comment: Did you look for special editions and additional merchandise like artbooks and such? They could contain all of those.

Comment: @Hakase I've had trouble finding anything of it really - search results usually turn up 'stretch' goals for 'anime' crowdfunding projects :(

Comment: I searched ストレッチ 漫画 (Stretch manga) in Japanese to help strain out some of the overloaded definitions. I got a few results that looked semi-promising in that they did actually reference the manga itself, but I can't read Japanese well enough to get an answer out of it.

Comment: Well, if you finish compiling those, could you post us a link where you would have uploaded it ? I would be interested too :)